# filling text area base on name or class name visual basic

Tags: vba, vbscript, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to make an automation software for facebook.
So i am trying to insert some text in text area by class name because there is not any id on it but it's not working.

Here is my code:

TextArea:

```
<div class="innerWrap">
    <textarea 
        class="uiTextareaAutogrow input autofocus mentionsTextarea textInput DOMControl_placeholder" 
        title="Με τι ασχολείστε σήμερα;" 
        name="xhpc_message_text" 
        placeholder="Με τι ασχολείστε σήμερα;" 
        role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" autocomplete="off" 
        aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="typeahead_list_u_jsonp_10_13" 
        aria-haspopup="true" 
        onkeydown="run_with(this, [&quot;legacy:control-textarea&quot;], function()
            {TextAreaControl.getInstance(this)});" 
        id="u_jsonp_10_14" 
        aria-label="Με τι ασχολείστε σήμερα;" 
        style="height: 63px;">Με τι ασχολείστε σήμερα;
    </textarea>
</div>
```

and my code:

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

        Dim pulledtags = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("*")
        For Each Elem In pulledtags
            If Elem.GetAttribute("class") = "uiTextareaAutogrow input autofocus mentionsTextarea textInput DOMControl_placeholder" Then

                Elem.InnerText = TextBox1.Text

            End If
        Next

    End Sub
```

TextBox1 has a value on it.

Regards

Comment: I think this will be easier to accomplish with a clientside/javascript solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefer `document.getElementsByClassName("a b c")` which is agnostic as to the order of classes.

Use `Value` not `InnerText`:

```
 Elem.Value = TextBox1.Text
```